# Excel 2016 mac vba evaluate error

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am using Excel v16.9 on a mac running 10.13.3 and am trying to use the Evaluate function but it returns error `Error 2015`.

The line that causes the error is:

```
temp = Evaluate(GetWebDataTest("https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/IBM?modules=assetProfile", 269, 150))
```

When I step through the code, `GetWebDataTest` is correctly evaluated but when the function ends the value is not returned to the variable `test` instead it shows `Error 2015`

The value that `GetWebDataTest` returns is:

```
"sector":"Technology","longBusinessSummary":"International Business Machines Corporation provides information technology (IT) products and services wo
```

Is this a bug with the Mac version of Excel or I am doing something wrong.

**Update:**

Upon further investigation of the problem, I have narrowed it down to `Evaluate` not being able to return a string. Consider the following code:

```
 temp = Evaluate(RetText())
 temp1 = Evaluate(RetNo())

Public Function RetText() As String
    RetText = "Te"
End Function
Public Function RetNo()
    RetNo = 5
End Function
```

When run, `temp` throw an error - `Error 2029` whereas `temp1` correctly is assigned the value 5.

It looks as though `Evaluate` will fail if the resulting function tries to return a string.

Comment: It looks like the GetWebDataTest is cutting off part of the text. Evaluate ha a 255 character limit. Could this be the error?

Comment: @EmilyAlden: Thanks for the suggestion but `GetWebDataTest` returns 150 characters so is within the limit of Evaluate

Comment: What are you expecting to be the result of running `Evaluate` on that text?  If you're trying to parse JSON then that's not how it's done.

Comment: The GetWebDataTest... is held as a string, say `var`. What I am actually doing is passing `Evaluate(var)` and am expecting it to return the result of the function which in this case is `"sector....` as shown above. So the variable `temp` will hold the value returned by the function

Comment: That's not what Evaluate does.  You'd be *much* better off using an existing library like https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON to parse the full JSON response and then extracting what you need from that.

Comment: @TimWilliams: `Evaluate("formula")` converts the "formula" to a value which is exactly what I am trying to do. In my code the `Evaluate` function should run the `GetWebDataTest(...)` function and return the value. Maybe I wasn't clear in my original explanation. If I step through the code, it will correctly evaluate the function but when the function ends, the calculated value is not passed back to the `temp` variable.

Comment: You need to show us the code for GetWebDataTest - its impossible to say what the problem is without that.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams: See updated question for example code

Comment: Why are you using Evaluate at all?  You can just call the GetWebDataTest function and get the result.  Please go read the docs on Evaluate and then see if that’s really what you need.

Comment: The reason that I need to use Evaluate is that the function and its parameters are held in a variable. For example, the variable will hold `GetWebDataTest("url")`. url will change so, I need to use Evaluate to pass the correct url to the function.

Comment: The only variable here is the URL you pass in the call to `GetWebDataTest` - **there is no need for `Evaluate` in this context**, and it does not work as you appear to think it does (as indicated by your test cases).  Why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate tries to execute whatever it is given as a formula - so it thinks TE should be a defined Name which it can't find.

Try this:

```
Public Function RetText() As String
    RetText = "=""Te"""
End Function
```

or this

```
Public Function RetText() As String
    RetText = """Te"""
End Function
```